# Check for the change in selected value of select tag

Tags: jquery, html, html-select

How can i check if there any change occurred for dropdown box using jquery?

```
<select id="bonus">
     <option value="1">-$5000</option>
     <option value="2">-$2500</option>
     <option value="3">$0</option>
     <option value="4" selected="selected">$1</option>
     <option value="5">We really appreciate your work</option>
</select>
```

Initial  selected value is 4. I have to recognize whether any update/change occurred for the tag
Same i have to check for multiselect dropdown also.

Comment: look at [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/change/ this might help

Comment: if the user just select option 5, and then he reverted back to 4 itself. . change will treat this as a change . But actually value is not changed. i want to handle this case also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$("select").change(function () {
       var txt = $(this).val();
       $(this).next('span.out').text(txt);
    }).trigger('change');​
```

OR

```
$("select").each(function(){

    var select = $(this),
        out = select.next();

    select.change(function () {
        out.text(select.val());
    });

}).trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 2):

try doing this in document ready

```
$( "#bonus" ).change(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
});
```

Reference : http://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 1):

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PTRSC/1/)**

The [**.change**](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event in jQuery handles both single select and multi select for dropdowns.

here is the code for your select

```
$(function(){
    $("#bonus").change(function(){
        alert('changed');
    });
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: if the user just select option 5, and then he reverted back to 4 itself. . change will treat this as a change . But actually value is not changed. i want to handle this case also